# QMake keeps compiling with c++98 instead of set c++11

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qmake, c++98

Hi I have a problem with qmake since it allways set the version to c++98 even when I have in my .pro file this:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

I was tring various combinations with:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX11= -std=c++11 or CONFIG+= strict_c++ c++11
```

but it still do not worked. My output from `make` is still showing this error: `error in c++98 could not convert from <brace-enclosed initializer list> to 'const std::vector<>'`

Comment: This is not how error looks like. Copy and paste the exact message.

Comment: I cannot copy from putty for unknown reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11`. Depending on your compiler version, you may need to set this to `c++0x` (GCC before about 4.7 or so use this).

Comment: this accually did something but there is new error: `g++: error: c++11: file does not exist`

Comment: Here is the whole .pro file https://pastebin.com/4G3GSsDc . And new error is that it cannot find the first .o file : 

    `g++ error: c++11: file does not exists 
    make: *** [Board.o] Error 1` after the  `qmake -o Makefile file.pro `

Comment: You need to set a target and potentially might want to set a template, e.g. `TARGET = Cards` `TEMPLATE = app`. Probably also want `QT += core gui`

Comment: I though TARGET is optional, never mind I added everything but I get the same error